# 3d array to matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix called vec with two columns, vec[:,0] and vec[:,1]. P contains two matrices, P[0,:,:] and P[1,:,:]. I want to mulitiply P[0,:,:] with the first column of vec and multiply P[1,:,:] with the second column of vec. However, the operation P@vec also gives me the matrix product of P[0,:,:] with the second column of vec and the matrix product of P[1,:,:] with the first column of vec, which slows my code.

Is it possible to directly compute the pairs column 1 to matrix 1 and column 2 to matrix 2 without the "off" products?

```
import numpy as np

P=np.arange(50).reshape(2, 5, 5)
vec=np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)
have=P@vec
want=np.column_stack((have[0,:,0],have[1,:,1]))

have,want
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very powerful function in numpy called `np.einsum`. It can perform all kind of tensor contractions, axis reordering and matrix multiplication. For your example you could use

```
res = np.einsum('nij,jn->in', P, vec)
```

after which `res` is exactly like `want`.

How does this work:
You give the `np.einsum` function both your arrays as well as a signature (that `'nij,jn->in'` string) that tells the function how to multiply the arrays. In short, you want the third axis of the `P` tensor to be contracted with the first axis of `vec`. Therefore you choose the same index `j` in the signature string and leave it out in the part after the `->`. A mere broadcast is done if indices appear on the left and right hand side of the `->`, which is done here for the `n` and `i` indices.

A more complete explanation of this very powerful function with many examples of how to use it can be found at [the corresponding numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html).

Answer (score 1):

`@/matmul` handles `batches` nicely, but the rules are that for 3d arrays, the first dimension is the batch, and `dot` is done on the last 2 dimensions, with the usual "last of A with the second to the last of B" pairing.

It took a bit of reading to decipher you description but it appears that you want the first of `p` to the batch, and last of `vec` to be the batch.  That means `vec` needs to transformed to a (2,5,1) to work with the (2,5,5) `p`.

```
In [176]: P@vec.T[:,:,None]
Out[176]: 
array([[[  60],
        [ 160],
        [ 260],
        [ 360],
        [ 460]],

       [[ 695],
        [ 820],
        [ 945],
        [1070],
        [1195]]])
```

The result is (2,5,1).  We can squeeze out the the last to get (2,5), but apparently you want a (5,2)

```
In [179]: (P@vec.T[:,:,None])[...,0].T
Out[179]: 
array([[  60,  695],
       [ 160,  820],
       [ 260,  945],
       [ 360, 1070],
       [ 460, 1195]])
```

`np.einsum('nij,jn->in', P, vec)` does effectively the same, with the `n` as the `batch` dimension that is 'carried through' to the result, and sum-of-products on the shared `j` dimension.